# Part files in mapper Output Represent the Split?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Do part files which are generated as an output of a mapper only job as part-m-00000,Part-m-00001,so on represent the first input split, second input split and so on and are they generated sequentially ??

Comment: your question is little unclear. The file names are sequential so what do you mean by `are they generated sequentially `?

Comment: by sequentially i mean as what i have studied that which ever mapper executes first it starts giving the output but how are they written?? Does the first split means first mapper and second means second and so on and does part files have any relation with splits ???

Answer (score 1):

May not be. The split array returned by the getSplits() method is sorted into order based on size, so that the biggest go first. This sorted array is passed farther down and map tasks are created for each element. So, the ordering information would be lost when you do the sort.

Reference: `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter` class. See method `writeSplits(..)`

**Link to source code:**
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobSubmitter.java

---

**Further reading on how the file names are decided:**

Once the task id is determined, the name of the file is decided by the `getDefaultWorkFile` API available in `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat` class. Here is the documentation:

> ```
> getDefaultWorkFile
>
> public Path getDefaultWorkFile(TaskAttemptContext context,
>                                String extension)
>                         throws IOException
> Get the default path and filename for the output format.
> Parameters:
> context - the task context
> extension - an extension to add to the filename
> Returns:
> a full path $output/_temporary/$taskid/part-[mr]-$id
> ```

This means "part" is postfixed with the task type, 'm' for maps, 'r' for reduces and the task partition number (i.e. task id). For example, the file for the first map of the job the generated name will be 'part-m-00000'.

Javadoc reference: [https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/FileOutputFormat.html#getDefaultWorkFile(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, java.lang.String)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/FileOutputFormat.html#getDefaultWorkFile(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext,%20java.lang.String))

The older `FileOutputFormat` API sitting in `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` package also works in a similar way. Here is the reference: [https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileOutputFormat.html#getUniqueName(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf, java.lang.String)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileOutputFormat.html#getUniqueName(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: does that means that the m-00000 represent the first split m-00001 represent the second and so on?? what u are talking about is taskid i am asking whether they mean they belong to first split second split and so on??

Comment: May not be. Just edited my answer to show the full picture.

Comment: Can we control how output of mapreduce is written what i mean is if i want that content of first split should be written first and then second and so on can we control the way hadoop writes the output???

Comment: For that, do not use the default FileOutputFormat or it's subclasses directly. Extend the class and override the methods. Now, FileOutputFormat is an abstract. You must be using one of it's subclasses, for example TextInputFormat. Just extend that class. You will also need to extend the RecordWriter and Splits because getDefaultWorkFile is a static method